# placing two divs (javascript ads) beside each other

Tags: html

I'm trying to place two ads at the top of my posts in Wordpress. The ad code is as follows.

```
<div id="im-12345">
  <script async src="https://adcompany.co.jp/script/v1/spot.js"></script>
  <script>(window.adsbyadcompany=window.adsbyadcompany||[]).push({pid:20987,mid:523741,asid:1709676,type:"banner",display:"inline",elementid:"im-033d1f1835404bbf80e342e2e182d96b"})</script>
</div>
```

I've googled how to place two divs beside each other and via trial and error have tried to get two of these ads beside each other without success (the ads just stack on top of each other).

Any idea how I could achieve this? Preferably using HTML with no css (I'm not a coder and wouldn't even know where to past the css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS `flexbox`. The `flexbox` will display the `div`'s next to each other, and resize them to fit. So in your case, the **parent** of your two `divs` needs to be a `flexbox`, (CSS `display: flex;`), and they will both automaticaly be next to each other.

If you specificaly want to do this from your html page, just add `style"display: flex;"` in your parent div, for example:

```
<div id="container" style="display: flex;">
    <div id="ad1"></div>
    <div id="ad2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To find out more, check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

Adding a tiny amount of CSS is not hard: use the `style` attribute on your div to add `display: flex`:

```
<div id="im-12345" style="display: flex">
  <script async src="https://adcompany.co.jp/script/v1/spot.js"></script>
  <script>(window.adsbyadcompany=window.adsbyadcompany||[]).push({pid:20987,mid:523741,asid:1709676,type:"banner",display:"inline",elementid:"im-033d1f1835404bbf80e342e2e182d96b"})</script>
</div>
```

Before you change your code you can try this out in the "developer tools" of your browser, e.g. [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Any idea how to make the two divs have a small space between each other?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to define style to the div, you can use #im-12345 {...}.